# Rails undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, undefined

Why is this undefined? Does it have something to do with the `@current_user`?

I'm trying to create tasks for my challenges. And the created task should get /achievements. However, I get a GET 500 error.

This is the error I get:

````
NoMethodError at /achievements
==============================

> undefined method `achievements' for #<User:0x00000105140dd8>

app/controllers/achievements_controller.rb, line 5
--------------------------------------------------

``` ruby
    1   class AchievementsController < ApplicationController
    2   
    3   
    4     def index
>   5       @achievements = @current_user.achievements
    6       render :json => @achievements
    7     end
    8   
    9     def new    10       @achievement = Achievement.new
````

**This is my code in my controller**

```
class AchievementsController < ApplicationController


  def index
    @achievements = @current_user.achievements
    render :json => @achievements
  end

  def new
    @achievement = Achievement.new
    render :json => @achievement
  end

  #create a new achievment and add it to the current user
  #check then set the acheivments pub challenge id to the current pub challenge
  def create
    @achievement = Achievement.new achievement_params
    @achievement.user = @current_user.id
    @achievement.pub_challenge = params[:id]
    if @achievement.save
      # render :json => @achievement #{ status: 'ok'}
    else
      render :json => {:errors => @achievement.errors}
    end
  end

  def show
    @achievement = Achievement.find params[:id]
    render :json => @achievement

  end

  def destroy
    @achievement = Achievement.find params[:id]
    @achievement.destroy
  end

  private
    def achievement_params
    params.require(:achievement).permit(:pub_challenges)
    end


end
```

Comment: Please show us the relevant sections of your user model too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are missing the `has_many :achievements` relation in your User model.

Answer (score 9):

You'll need to create the [ActiveRecord associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) you require:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :achievements
end

#app/models/achievement.rb
class Achievement < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
end
```

This will give you the ability to call the `achievements` method on any `User` objects you have.

---

**Error**

The error you have is described as such:

```
undefined method `achievements' for #<User:0x00000105140dd8>
```

This basically means that you're trying to call an undefined method on a `User` object. Might sound simple, but really, most people don't understand it.

To explain properly, you have to remember that Rails, by virtue of being built on Ruby is [*object orientated*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming). This means that *everything* you do in Rails should be structured around objects - which are defined in your `Models`:

[image]

This means that each time you call an *object*, you're actually above to invoke a series of "methods" which will give you the ability to either manipulate the object itself, or any of the associated functionality it has.

The problem you have is that your `User` object doesn't have the `achievements` method. Whilst you could simply do the following to fix the issue, because it's Rails, you'll need to populate the record with associative data:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :achievements #-> what you need

   def achievements
      #this will also fix the error you see, although it's fundamentally incorrect
   end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Something that helped me with this type of error was that the database table was missing the relevant column. Adding the required column to the database fixed the issue.